# What does 'serval days away from' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

Her cart was nearly overflowing in preparation for **several days away** from her family, and she still had packing to do at home.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serval

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a one-off mistake and will never confuse anyone else ever again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that she will have a long period without the family.

Away means "far from" in this context.

And there is a typo: **several**

Answer (score 1):

Several days (spent) away from her family.

Answer (score 0):

> Her cart was nearly overflowing in preparation for **several** days away from her family, and she still had packing to do at home.

I think it's a spelling mistake?